# What is wrong with this battery

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

I recently encountered a battery that was installed in a vintage lawn mower. The battery was dated 9/19 but would not start the engine, it would not even cause the relay to click. The voltage on the battery terminals is 12.04 vdc. So I grabbed a different 12 volt battery and installed it. It started right away.

I put the battery on the shelf and hooked my charger to it. After a few hours of charging nothing changed so I checked further - the battery is a calcium battery. Does that explain any of what I am seeing? The battery has zero capacity at 12 vdc, is there anything I can do or should do with it? The warranty was 6 months - now expired.

Comment: How it was stored? Was it disconnected from mower? Was it under trickle charge during storage? Did the battery freeze during storage?

Comment: It sounds like this battery is damaged. Probably the only thing that can be done is to recycle it.

Comment: The battery was left on the mower with no special attention. The owner just assumed it was ok How can the battery be damaged? What mechanism?

Comment: Probably the battery wasn’t fully charged when it was left unused for a long time. And one thing about lead acid batteries is that if not fully charged before a long period of storage sulfation starts on the plates and this seriously reduces the capacity(Ah) of the Lead Acid battery. Is it a flooded or VRLA battery?

Comment: Fairly certain that the battery didn't get damaged from freezing. In answer to the question  - it is a lead acid battery with calcium somehow involved in its manufacture. I was unaware of such a battery before this one, I believe it is a flooded cell with 300+ cranking amps capability much higher than most other lawn mower batteries. As far as sulfation, of course I don't know, but would that cause no output capability with over 12 vdc showing?

Comment: One other thing, it was operated all summer with the battery installed and worked well - how many times IDK.

Answer (score 0):

The calcium battery has a higher open circuit voltage than a regular lead-acid battery. Thus it also requires a higher voltage to charge it. The fact that the voltage reading was 12 vdc confused the poster, who was used to regular lead-acid batteries. The calcium battery was NOT bad - it was depleted of all charge. The reason that the battery was believed to be dead was that it had 0 current output with 12 vdc reading and attempts to charge it had failed.

A good lead-acid reads 12.6 vdc open circuit. When depleted of charge with all good cells the same battery reads 11 vdc or more, but less than 12 vdc. If the battery reads 10.5 vdc, the chances are that one of its cells is bad.

The calcium battery on the other hand reads 13.5 vdc open circuit. When depleted of charge with all good cells the same battery reads 12 vdc or more, but less than 13 vdc. If the battery reads 11.5 vdc, the chances are it has one dead cell.

The net is that the calcium battery as seen by the op was completely discharged. When the smart charger was put on it, it charged for a significant amount of time at very high amperage of 20 amps so that the smart charger decided something was wrong with the battery. The op thought so too. But after reading more about calcium batteries, it was discovered that a higher charge voltage was needed.

A different old standard charger was employed. This charger began charging at almost 15 vdc. After an hour the battery was being charged at the max that the charger puts out and the current was down to 2 amps. This continued for some time, but the current eventually was down to nearly 0 amps and the voltage remained at the maximum of about 15.6 vdc.

In all probability, the charging circuit of the vintage John Deere lawn tractor it was on does not put out a high enough voltage to charge the calcium battery (if it was working at all). The owner of the lawn tractor gave it away so it was removed from the op's reach, though it appeared to be operating with the different battery installed (the battery installed was not new, but it might be capable of starting the tractor many times without being charged).

The calcium battery after being charged with a higher voltage, will be placed into service on a newer lawn tractor and the voltage checked to see to it that the battery is charging properly. The battery now tests good at 350 cca, and has 13.5 vdc open circuit reading.